# ¿Qué significa el valor de un puntero a miembro?

Tags: c++, puntero-a-función, puntero-a-miembro

Disponiendo de un objeto con varios miembros de diferentes tipos:

```
struct foo
{
    int x, y, z;
};
```

Si obtengo el puntero al primer elemento e imprimo dicho puntero obtengo un `1`, aunque esperaba un `0`<sup>1</sup>:

```
std::cout << &foo::x << '\n';
```

Esperaba obtener un `2` o un `5`<sup>2</sup> al obtener el puntero al segundo elemento de `foo`, pero el valor también es `1`:

```
std::cout << &foo::x << '\n'; // Muestra 1
std::cout << &foo::y << '\n'; // Muestra 1
```

Lo curioso es que el resultado es siempre `1` sea cual sea el miembro apuntado por el puntero a miembro:

```
struct foo
{
    int x{1}, y{2}, z{3};
    char a{'a'}, e{'e'}, i{'i'}, o{'o'}, u{'u'};
    float v{.111f}, w{.222f};

    void f1() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }
    void f2() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }
    void f3() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }
    void f4() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }
} f;

int main()
{
    for (auto m : { &foo::x, &foo::y, &foo::z })
        std::cout << "int: " << std::hex << m << std::dec << ' ' << f.*m << '\n';

    for (auto m : { &foo::a, &foo::e, &foo::i, &foo::o, &foo::u })
        std::cout << "char: " << std::hex << m << std::dec << ' ' << f.*m << '\n';

    for (auto m : { &foo::v, &foo::w })
        std::cout << "float: " << std::hex << m << std::dec << ' ' << f.*m << '\n';

    for (auto m : { &foo::f1, &foo::f2, &foo::f3, &foo::f4 }) {
        std::cout << "void(): " << std::hex << m << ' ';
        (f.*m)();
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> int: 1 1
> int: 1 2
> int: 1 3
> char: 1 a
> char: 1 e
> char: 1 i
> char: 1 o
> char: 1 u
> float: 1 0.111
> float: 1 0.222
> void(): 1 f1
> void(): 1 f2
> void(): 1 f3
> void(): 1 f4
> ```
>
> Y puede verse funcioando <kbd>[AQUÍ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UHSsnAVoc8jKBEBD)</kbd>.

Si todos los punteros a miembro valen `1` ¿Cómo se distinguen unos miembros de otros? ¿Qué significado tiene el valor de un puntero a miembro?

---

<sup>1</sup>C++ indexa desde `0`.

<sup>2</sup>Si empezamos a contar desde `1` y sumamos cuatro bytes, el resultado sería `5`.

Comment: Me temo que no es exactamente así @RenatoA. `&foo::x` significa: "Obtén la dirección del miembro `x` en el objeto `foo`". `foo` no es un espacio de nombres.

Comment: Claro que son diferentes, `&foo.x` ni siquiera tiene sentido.

Comment: Y ya se lo que significa `&foo::x`, mas no significa lo que has expresado.

Answer (score 4):

Los punteros a miembro no son tipos *al uso* y para muestra un botón:

```
auto x = &foo::x;
std::cout << (int)x; // error: invalid cast from type 'int foo::*' to type
```

Como se ve, no es posible hacer un `cast` para un puntero a miembro (independientemente de que sea a función o a variable miembro) y esto ya nos dice que aunque se parezcan a los punteros tradicionales algo cambia por debajo.

Otra muestra es que el tamaño que ocupa el puntero no coincide con el de un puntero al uso:

```
std::cout << sizeof(x) << '\n'; // imprime 8 en 32 bits
```

Esto es llamativo... ¿Qué contienen estos 8 bytes?

Vamos a investigarlo con un ejemplo sencillo:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int x{1}, y{2}, z{3};
    char a{'a'}, e{'e'}, i{'i'}, o{'o'}, u{'u'};
    float v{.111f}, w{.222f};

    void f1() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }
    void f2() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }
    void f3() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }
    void f4() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__; }

} f;

union test
{
  decltype(&foo::x) x;
  struct {
    int a;
    int b;
  };
};

int main()
{

    for (auto m : { &foo::x, &foo::y, &foo::z })
    {
      test t;
      t.x = m;
      std::cout << "int: " << std::hex << t.a << '-' << t.b << std::dec << ' ' << f.*m << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo <kbd>[AQUÍ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UHSsnAVoc8jKBEBD)</kbd>

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
int: 0-0 1
int: 4-0 2
int: 8-0 3
```

Ahora podemos observar como los punteros a miembro **sí** que cambian. El puntero está almacenando el offset a aplicar en función de la posición de cada variable, lo cual tiene sentido... sin este dato el programa no sería capaz de acceder a la variable *apuntada*.

Si bien necesitaría investigar un poco más para explicar de dónde sale ese `1` constante, ha quedado claro que los punteros a función *sí* que almacenan un offset que permitirá al código encontrar el valor buscado en cada momento.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que confunde un poco es la sintaxis para los punteros a miembro. 
Por ejemplo, en

```
decltype(&foo::x) p;  // variable de tipo puntero a dato miembro
                      // de foo, que sea del mismo tipo que foo::x
p = &foo::x;          // "inicializada": ahora p puede apuntar a
                      // los x de cualquier foo,

f.*p = 2;             // y se puede acceder a f.x a través del puntero p.
```

pero este puntero `p` también podría apuntarse a otro x de otro foo, y acceder desde él a su correspondiente x:

```
foo f2;
f2.*p = 50;
```

O sea, usamos el mismo p para apuntarlo primero a f.x y después a f2.x.

¿Y por qué se muestra siempre un 1 como valor de puntero a miembro?
Porque se está mostrando el puntero convertido implícitamente a `bool`.

[*Edito*:]

```
std::cout << "p == " << p << '\n';  // va a mostrar 1 (true)
p = nullptr;                        // null member pointer value
                                    // de tipo foo::x 
                                    // (ver Estándar 7.12)
std::cout << "p == " << p << '\n';  // va a mostrar 0 (false)
```

Entonces, el "valor" de un puntero a miembro de una clase sólo puede ser 1 (true) o 0 (false), pero no se puede mostrar su dirección porque es un `puntero a miembro de una clase` y por lo tanto no apunta a nada, al menos hasta el momento en que apunte a un `miembro de un objeto` en concreto.
*[fin de la edición]*

Creo que con este fragmento de código añadido al de la pregunta puede aclara algo las cosas:

```
std::cout << "\nLa direccion de un puntero a miembro se convierte en bool (en este caso siempre es true)\n";
std::cout << "&foo::x == " << std::boolalpha << &foo::x << std::noboolalpha << " == " << &foo::x << '\n';

std::cout << "\n Si px es un puntero al tipo de foo::x\n";
int foo::* px = &foo::x;
std::cout << "int foo::* px = &foo::x;\n";

std::cout << "Se puede mostrar su direccion:\n";
std::cout << "&(f.*px) == " << (void *)(&(f.*px)) << '\n';

std::cout << "\ny modificar f.x a traves de esa direccion:\n";
*(&(f.*px)) = 100;
std::cout << "*(&(f.*px)) = 100; ==> f.x == " << std::dec << f.x << '\n';

std::cout << "\naunque la forma natural de hacerlo es:\n";
f.*px = 200;
std::cout << "f.*px = 200; ==> f.x == " << f.x << '\n';
```

Comment: Cuando muestras la dirección, no muestras el valor del puntero a miembro si no la dirección de memoria del miembro de una instancia (que al ser `x` el primer miembro de `foo`, coincidirá con la dirección de memoria de la instancia). Así que no se aclara el significado del valor del puntero a miembro.

Comment: Es así, la dirección de memoria de un puntero a miembro no se puede mostrar, sólo true o false. Edité mi respuesta con una nota adicional.

Answer (score 2):

Un puntero a miembro es una cosa ... curiosa.

## En el inicio

C++ hereda *mucho* de C; entre otras cosas, toma de él el concepto de *función* .

#### Funciones no-miembro

Una función es simple de definir/declarar:

```
void algo( int v ) { // hacemos algo con v ... }
```

Los argumentos son fáciles de ver: es lo que se encuentra *entre los paréntesis*. En este caso, `int v`: un solo argumento, de tipo `int`. Y podemos acceder, dentro el cuerpo de la función, por su nombre: `v`.

Un *puntero* a la función anterior tiene la siguiente forma:

```
void ( * )( int );
```

Un poco *feo*, pero, aparte de eso, es un puntero *corriente y moliente*:

```
void ( *puntero_a_algo )( ) = algo;
```

Con eso, asignamos a nuestro puntero a función la dirección de memoria en la que se encuentra nuestra función `algo( int )`.

Ahora, pasemos a las

#### Funciones-miembro:

```
struct Algo {
  int total;

  void algo( int total ) { this->total = this->total + total; }
};
```

Ahora, las cosas se *complican* un poco. Seguimos teniendo un argumento *explícito*, `total`. Y, desde dentro de la función, accedemos a él igualmente por su nombre: `total`.

**Pero** ... tenemos un *elemento* **adicional**: `this`.

Ese `this` es un puntero **a la instancia *en uso* de la clase**.

Las funciones-miembro **no estáticas** reciben un argumento *implícito*; no es necesario declararlo, lo tenemos por el simple hecho de ser una función-miembro. Y, normalmente, pasa desapercibido. No es necesario usarlo *de forma explícita*, salvo en contadas excepciones (como el caso expuesto, con *colisión* de identificadores).

Ese argumento extra, `this`, **es obligatorio**. Una función-miembro **no puede funcionar** sin el, puesto que lo usa como base para todos los accesos a variables-miembro no estáticas. Aunque nosotros no lo indiquemos, cuando hacemos algo tal que

```
struct Algo {
  int x;

  void inc( ) { x += 1; }
};
```

en realidad, el compilador genera algo que se parece mas a

```
struct Algo {
  int x;

  void inc( ) { this->x += 1; }
};
```

#### Punteros a funciones-miembro

La **necesidad** de `this` es el motivo de la existencia de punteros-a-funciones-miembro. Nos recuerda a nosotros e informan al compilador de que ese puntero **no tiene sentido** sin un objeto `this` sobre el que aplicarlo.

Adicionalmente, **impide** la mezcla de punteros. El tipo de un puntero-a-función-miembro es distinto al de un puntero a función no-miembro; lo que nos impide llarmar a funciones equivocadas por error, cosa que, debido a `this`, provacaría resultados ... curiosos :-)

Ese es el motivo de la existencia de diferentes tipos de punteros: para funciones (o variables) -miembro, y para funciones (o variables) externas, independientes, o como las queramos llamar.

## Relatividad y desplazamiento

Los punteros-a-miembro no almacenan direcciones *absolutas*; su uso es como argumento de los operadores `->*` y `.*`. Proporcionan mayor facilidad de lectura, y evitan los errores.

#### C

En C, se permiten cosas curiosas con los punteros:

```
struct algo_s {
  int x;
  double z;
} Algo;

size_t off = offsetof( struct algo_s, z );

double *ptrz = (double *)( ( (char *)&Algo ) + off );
```

Nuestro `ptrz` se ha obtenido **sumando** a la dirección de `Algo` el desplazamiento en *bytes* relativo a su miembro `z`.

Esto, aparte de *ofensivo a la vista*, es **bastante** proclive a errores.

¡ Menos mal que llegó ...

#### C++ !

Este lenguaje mejora muchas cosas de su *progenitor*; de entrada, es **mucho mas *tiquismiquis* con los tipos**.

Durante su diseño, se pensó: ¿ no podría mejorarse lo de los accesos relativos ? Y, además resultó que **era necesario** mejorarlo, por un motivo (que ya casí estamos, un poco mas de paciencia).

Así que se diseñaron los operadores `->*` y `.*`, **específicos** para acceso relativos; es decir, accesos formados por la combinación de un puntero base y un **dato** (que no puntero) relativo al desplazamiento.

De un *plumazo*, se solucionaron *un par* de cosillas: su *feo* y propenso a errores *modo de empleo*, y ...

## Funciones virtuales

Esto es una característica de C++ muy util. Permite acceder a *versiones* de determinadas funciones.

En una jerarquía de clases, las clases hijas pueden proporcionar su propia versión de una función. Las funciones virtuales permiten acceder a esas *versiones adicionales* ... ¡ mediante punteros (o referencias) a sus clases-base ! No es necesario tener un puntero del tipo exacto de la clase. Nos basta con uno a una clase *padre*.

No voy a entrar en detalles (se aleja del motivo de la pregunta), remito al artículo de la <kbd>[wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_virtual)</kbd> sobre ello.

#### Implementación

El compilador **tienen libre disposición** para implementar el mecanismo de *función virtual*. Se espera de él que provoque la mínima sobrecarga posible (tanto en tiempo de llamada con en *bytes* extra ocupados), pero, por lo demás, puede implementarlo como le plazca.

#### VTABLE

Es el método estándar para proveer el mecanismo de funciones virtuales.

Se basa en una *arreglo*, en donde cada elemento del mismo es un puntero a la posición de memoria en la que está guardada el verdadero código de la función.

#### VPTR

Dicha tabla, por si misma, es *inútil*. Es necesario un mecanismo para *enlazar* los datos de una instancia de clase con su propia `VTABLE`. Se suele utilizar un *puntero*, llamado `VPTR`.

¿ Donde se coloca ese `VPTR` ? Pues **justo delante del primer dato real de la clase**; siempre y cuando, claro está, dicha clase defina/declare alguna función `virtual`.

## Desenlace

Pues ya sabemos lo que es un puntero-a-miembro. Es un **tipo de dato opaco**, cuyo contenido es solo conocido por el compilador, capaz de contener un desplazamiento sobre un puntero base, **obviando los detalles de implementación de las funciones virtuales**.

Recordemos que dicho mecanismo **es dependiente de la implementación**. Algunos compiladores usan `VTABLE` y `VPTR`. Otros, pueden utilizar diversos métodos. Y el `VPTR` puede colocarse donde el compilador estime: justo delante de los datos de instancia, o en medio. O donde el compilador decida.

Ese mismo mecanismo es el que obliga a usar los punteros-a-miembro **también** para el acceso a variables-miembro. Dependiendo de si la clase tiene o no funciones virtuales (o hereda de clases con ellos), el desplazamiento relativo a un dato-miembro puede variar de un compilador a otro.

Ese es también el motivo de que sea opaco y no un puntero *ordinario*: solo el compilador conoce los detalles de su propia implementación. Y puede no ser fácil de transformar en algo *comprensible para humanos*.